# Unable to get text from element in nightwatchjs

Tags: nightwatch.js

I'm currently using nightwatchjs (latest version) and I'm trying to get the text of the element below ("Welcome to the newest....."), but I can't seem to find it.

[image]

Currently, I'm using the following code;

```
browser.getText('css selector', '.bfs-details__about-seller__why-buy p', function(result) {
        console.log('element text = ', result.value);
});
```

But I get an empty value.

Am I missing something obvious here?

thanks

Comment: I've also tried _div.bfs-details__about-seller__why-buy p_ but got the same empty result.

Answer (score 0):

As I see it, the problem is not the selector but how you try to log it.

Try `console.log('element text = ' + result.value);`

Or as an alternative (thats how I do it):

`browser.getText('css selector', '.bfs-details__about-seller__why-buy p', function(result) {
     myValue = result.value;
 });`

`browser.perform(function () {
    console.log(myValue)
 });`

Why use perform: [Nightwatch API Perform](https://nightwatchjs.org/api/perform.html)